# Safari 5.1.7 flexslider/jquery tools conflict z-index bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools, flexslider

I'm building a new site here: http://www.bigideaadv.com/wright/

Works fine in IE 7-9, Firefox, and Chrome.

Safari has conflict with the Flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and jQuery Tools (http://jquerytools.org/)

If I remove the line:

```
    $jsk(".scrollable").scrollable({circular: true, speed: '1000'});
```

from my javascript, safari displays correctly. But I need this called for one of the modules. There used to be a TypeOf error: ... is not a function but I resolved that.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. It was a syntax issue in the javascript. There were some other conflicts with Cufon font replacement though. Had to choose another (better) method. Using @font-face with a web ready font seemed to clear up all the issues.